# How to replace deprecated control HorizontalDivider?

Tags: sapui5

The control `sap.ui.commons.HorizontalDivider` is deprecated since version 1.38 of both sapui5 and openui5. How can I replace this control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a horizontal divider the HTML tag `<HR/>` (horizontal ruler) can be displayed in an instance of `sap.ui.core.HTML`.

So instead of

```
   new sap.ui.commons.HorizontalDivider()
```

you can use

```
   new sap.ui.core.HTML({content:"<hr/>"})
```

to get a horizontal divider (which looks almost identical to me).